# Переход между Activity срабатывает два раза

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Здравствуйте столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть фрагмент из которого запускается Activity с такой темой:

```
<style name="AppThemeDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Код запуска этой активити так-же довольно прост:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            MusicManager.continueMusic = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), UnlockPartActivity.class);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
            BlockFragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_UNLOCK);
        }
```

Эта Activity запускается и вроде бы все хорошо. Но если быстро нажать два раза на кнопку которая запускает это активность, то она откроется два раза. Этого быть не должно. В голову только приходит временно блокировать кнопку или снимать обработчик до выхода из активити. Однако может есть более правильные способы чтобы исправить такое поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Направление мыслей правильное, от "Самых быстрых стрелков на Диком Западе", в случае с `Activity`, спасаться получается блокировкой нажатий, вводя `boolean lock;`-переменную или же установкой `.setClickable(false)` на необходимом компоненте `View`.

В случае с `Fragment`-ами можно ввести проверку на существование уже запущенного `Fragment` с аналогичным `tag`-ом. И запуск `Fragment` предоставить самому себе:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    ...
    public void show(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        String tag = getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
            show(fragmentManager, tag);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Наследник `DialogFragment` - используется для примера, та же практика работает и на прямых наследниках `Fragment`.

Хотя среди разработчиков заметил частую практику игнорировать наличие возможности множественного запуска.

Comment: Диалог сделан не в виде fragment'a а в виде activity. Про теги у фрагментов знаю и они даже используются. Но так как был нужен стиль диалога, было принято решение использовать именно Activity.

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко DialogFragment я использовал в качестве примера, чтобы обозначить, что нет разницы использования данного метода для Fragment-а и DialogFragment-а, корень у них один - Fragment :)